# To + (verb) as infinitive/gerund

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, american-english, british-english

I have a question on preposition ‘to’.

When we use verb after ‘to’ we use either infinitives or verb in ing format but my question is:

1. will the word ‘to’ be a preposition in both the case? also,
2. verb in ing format is Gerund right? and
3. is infinitive a verb?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: [grammar corrections: Is the word "to" a preposition in both cases? Are all verbs with ing gerunds?]

Answer (score 1):

You said: "When we use verb after ‘to’ we use either infinitives or verb in ing format."  This is incorrect - you can't have "to" followed by an *-ing* participle.  You can't say "to seeing".

(It is possible to concoct sentences where "to"+participle is valid, e.g. "I want to get back to being me."  But "to" here doesn't fulfil the same role as it does when it marks an infinitive.)

It is true that infinitives and *-ing* participles can be used in similar ways *in some cases* (compare "I like to play" with "I like playing").

### To

The "to" that comes before an infinitive isn't a preposition.  It is an infinitive marker.

### -ing

Traditional grammars distinguish two classes of *-ing* words - participles (which act like adjectives) and gerunds (which act like nouns).  However, neither of the two major English grammar books of recent decades consider this a useful distinction.  Quirk, Greenbaum et al. (*A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*) use the term "*-ing* participle" to encompass the full range of uses of the "-ing" form of the verb, whilst Huddleston & Pullum (*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) use the term "gerund-participle" in the same way.

### Infinitives

You asked whether the infinitive is a verb.  Yes, the infinitive is a form of the verb.  All non-modal verbs have infinitives.  The infinitive may appear with "to" (as in "I want *to see* it"), or it may be a bare infinitive without "to" (as in "I can *see* it").

Answer (score 0):

> will the word ‘to’ be a preposition in both the case? also,

*To* is a preposition in any case.

> verb in ing format is Gerund right? and

*-ing* words can be either gerunds (noun-like) or present participles (adjective/adverb-like).  If you substitute "X-ing" for "to X", then it's a gerund.

> is infinitive a verb?

Infinitives/gerunds are called *verbals* because they share properties of both nouns and verbs. They fit into slots in sentences where nouns are expected.

Comment: The "to" that occurs in infinitival clauses is a member of the category (part of speech)  'subordinator'. It's function in the clause is that of 'marker'.

Comment: What are some other examples of subordinators?

Comment: I don't call to a subordinator. I call it a function word, as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word They are considered to be a "closed class" of words as new ones do not **usually** spring up in a language.

Comment: Whatever you call it (I call it an infinitive marker or an infinitive-marking particle), it shouldn't be considered a preposition.